# Correct method to get installed application path by app. name in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, path, installation

I use this function **to find any installed application**.

But the parameter "InstallLocation" doesn't work at all.

Any clue?

Thanks!!

```
void FindApplication(string appName)
{
    StringBuilder sbProductCode = new StringBuilder(39);
    int iIdx = 0;
    while (0 == MsiEnumProducts(iIdx++, sbProductCode))
    {
        Int32 productNameLen = 512;
        StringBuilder sbProductName = new StringBuilder(productNameLen);

        MsiGetProductInfo(sbProductCode.ToString(), "ProductName", sbProductName, ref productNameLen);

        if (sbProductName.ToString().Contains(appName))
        {
             Int32 installDirLen = 2048;
             StringBuilder sbInstallDir = new StringBuilder(installDirLen);
             MsiGetProductInfo(sbProductCode.ToString(),"InstallLocation", sbInstallDir, ref installDirLen);

             string result = string.Format("ProductName {0}: {1}", sbProductName, sbInstallDir);
             }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've visited the following links, and they don't appear to be outdated:

- [MsiGetProductInfo function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [MsiGetProductInfoEx function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370131%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The only keys I see that can be used are these:

- **ARPINSTALLLOCATION**
- **INSTALLDIR**
- INSTALLPROPERTY_INSTALLLOCATION
- INSTALLLOCATION

I should point out that it appears `MsiGetProductInfoEx` (second link) should be used to gather information on published/installed products added by another user; and requires administrative privledges.

Answer (score -1):

I found other solution and it works fine.

```
string FindPathByInstalledAppEXEName(string appEXEName)
{
    string path = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Installer\Assemblies");

        string regfilepath = string.Empty;
        if (key != null)  // Make sure there are Assemblies
        {
            foreach (string Keyname in key.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                if (Keyname.IndexOf(appEXEName) > 0)
                {
                    regfilepath = Keyname;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(regfilepath))
        {
            string fullpath = "";
            for (int a = 0; a < regfilepath.Length; a++)
            {
                if (regfilepath.IndexOf("|", a, 1) > 0)
                    fullpath += "\\";
                else
                    fullpath += regfilepath.Substring(a, 1);
            }
            path = fullpath.Substring(0, fullpath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
        }
    }
    catch // (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    return path;
}
```